# PyCharm + IPython debug in external terminal

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, ipython

I am wondering is it possible to attach process of debugging in PyCharm IDE to external IPython terminal.

Here is a picture which would describe this scenario:

[image: end_result]

Here are steps how I would like to reproduce this scenario:

1.) Set breakpoint at any line of code in PyCharm IDE.

2.) When IDE encounters line of code where breakpoint is located, it should open terminal, start ipython and load all variables / modules as if normal debugging would occur.

3.) Continue and step into / out should be reflected in terminal

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, PyCharm has all of these features built in! There's no need to launch another, separate terminal window and attach it to the debugger - PyCharm will take care of that. You can find more information here:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/python-console.html

Specifically, once you start debugging the "Debug" window should pop up. That should have two tabs - "Debugger" and "Console". On the "Console" tab, there's a button that has the tooltip "Start Python Prompt" (right below the trash can). This will launch an Ipython terminal within the console.

Comment: Well, you do if you want an ANSI-capable interactive debug console...